# What does NSApp hide: actually do with the NSWindow instances?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, nswindow, nsapplication

I'm working on an `NSWindow` subclass and I'm running into some strange behavior that makes me question some of my assumptions about how windows work on Mac OS X.

What precisely happens to `NSWindow` instances when `[[NSApplication sharedApplication] hide: self]` is called?

All windows that do not return NO to `-(BOOL)canHide` disappear from the screen. Then all windows re-appear when the application becomes active or `[NSApplication sharedApplication] unhide: self]` is called.

I had assumed that this would be achieved by taking a snapshot of the current window state, then calling `orderOut:` on all `NSWindow` instances and then performing the whole thing backwards when `unhide:` is called.

That does not seem to be the case, however. The `orderOut:` method of my `NSWindow` subclass isn't called.. in fact it's not hidden either. It does set `setCanHide:` to YES though.. what's happening?

Any insights would be very much appreciated.

Best regards,

Frank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fire up Instruments and find out for yourself! On my machine (10.6.4) and a 32-Bit application, `[NSApplication hide:]` calls `ShowHideProcess`. It's documented there:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Reference/Process_Manager/process_mgr_ref.pdf

The `ShowHideProcess` then calls `CPSPostHideReq` (*something in CoreGraphics*).

But there is no orderOut:, actually no `objc_msgSend()` at all.

What do you need it for? Or were you just curious? Because for most cases, you should do just fine listening for the `NSApplicationWill/DidHideNotification`.

Comment: Thanks for having a look. I did pretty much the same thing in the end, single stepping through the debugger, but it's not the kind of thing that I'm very comfortable with. I thought somebody might have some idea on how this works from previous work.. as so often in OS X the Cocoa layer only does the surface work and then everything goes down into the Carbon layer. I was trying to do a lot of the window management myself because I needed a bit more control of window behavior than Cocoa usually gives you (windows changing layers); that would be fine if NSWindow actually did the whole job.

Comment: In the end, realizing that I couldn't get to all the required functionality by subclassing NSWindow or via notifications, I got a hybrid solution (overriding some window management tasks and doing some behind the scenes reconfiguring of NSWindow in response to application and window notifications) and it seems to work fine. It's just not very elegant. Thanks for your help.